# Customizing SharePoint 2010 MS RTE

Tags: branding, rich-text, html-editor

I found this blog -- [customizing rich text editor](http://blog.sharepoint.ch/2010/08/customizing-rich-text-editor-in.html), but what I don't understand is the part where the author writes

> Set the PrefixStyleSheet-Property of the RichHtmlField. The classname has to be lowercase!
>
> ```
> <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField id="Content" FieldName="PublishingPageContent" runat="server" PrefixStyleSheet="my-style-must-be-lowercase"/>
> ```

Where would I insert the above code? In the masterpage? Pagelayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that RichHtmlField uses it's own css classes, it has it's own default, and you can change it to your own by adding a prefix to css class name, thus if original class name were for example - RTE-Normal-1, with prefix it will be YourPrefix-Normal-1. You can check class names in page source.

To add this property for RichHtmlField you need to edit Page Layout, where you want to brand RichHtmlField.